# Restarting animations when popping a view controller

Tags: objective-c, ios5, uiviewanimation

I am trying to reuse the Ken Burns effect view created by Javier Berlana (Kudos to him by the way).

I have the view on my root view controller. When I push a new view controller and then pop it out, the animation on the view is stopped at the end of the animation. When the transition time passes it changes the image and the animations are working again.

I have looked around, but found no working solution for this problem. My last solution was to implement `pauseLayer` and `resumeLayer` shown here (at the bottom):

https://gist.github.com/1802341

I invoke those methods on `viewWillAppear` and `viewWillDisappear` of my view controller.

What should I do to pause/resume the animation?

I am developing for iOS 5.

Answer (score 1):

From the Ken Burns implementation, I see that the animation is handled through a loop:

```
- (void)_startAnimations:(NSArray *)images
{
  @autoreleasepool {

    for (uint i = 0; i < [images count]; i++) {

        self.currentImage = i;

        NSOperationQueue *mainQueue      = [NSOperationQueue mainQueue];
        NSInvocationOperation *operation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                             selector:@selector(_animate:) 
                                               object:[NSNumber numberWithInt:self.currentImage]];
        [mainQueue addOperations:[NSArray arrayWithObject:operation] waitUntilFinished:YES];

        sleep(self.timeTransition);
        i = (i == [images count]-1) && isLoop ? -1 : i; 
      }

   }
 }
```

One way to stop the animation is adding a flag, like this:

```
    for (uint i = 0; i < [images count]; i++) {

        if (!animationSuspended) {
          self.currentImage = i;

          NSOperationQueue *mainQueue      = [NSOperationQueue mainQueue];
          NSInvocationOperation *operation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                             selector:@selector(_animate:) 
                                               object:[NSNumber numberWithInt:self.currentImage]];
          [mainQueue addOperations:[NSArray arrayWithObject:operation] waitUntilFinished:YES];
          i = (i == [images count]-1) && isLoop ? -1 : i; 
        }  
        sleep(self.timeTransition);
      }
```

So, when you set the flag, the loop body is only executed to produce the delay (sleep), and the rest of the state remains unchanged.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It didn't work, when returning from another view controller the animation is dead (until a new image comes up).